# Potentials for Vector Fields on a Circle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, periodic-functions, potential-theory

This problem actually has three parts, and I have questions about each part. (What is in block quotes is the actual text of the problem.)

- Part (a):

  > Consider the vector field on the circle given by $\dot{\theta} = \cos
  > \theta$. (Note: $\dot{\theta} = \frac{d \theta}{dt}$) I need to show
  >   that this system has a single-valued potential $V(\theta)$; i.e., for
  >   each point on the circle, there is a well-defined value of $V$ such
  >   that $\dot{\theta}=-\frac{dV}{d\theta}$. (Then it says something
  >   parenthetically that kind of confuses me, as you'll see why in my
  >   question regarding Part (b): "As usual, $\theta$ and $\theta + 2\pi k$
  >   are to be regarded as the same point on the circle, for each integer
  >   $k$.")

For this part, essentially, we want to find a $V(\theta)$ such that $-\frac{dV}{d\theta} = \cos \theta$. So, by separation of variables, we obtain $V(\theta) = -\sin \theta + C$, where $C$ is a constant of integration.

Now, according to my understanding, "single-valued" means that each element of the function's domain maps to a single, well-defined element of its range, correct? As in, to call a function "single-valued" is kind of redundant, because by defintion of a bona fide function, it will be "single-valued" anyway.

**So, my question for this part is, do I just want to show that if $\theta$ and $\theta + 2\pi k$ are considered the same point on the circle, then $V(\theta) = V(\theta + 2\pi k)$ here? Or, if not, how do I prove that $V(\theta)$ is single-valued?**

- Part (b):

> Now, consider $\dot{\theta} = 1$. Show that there is no single-valued potential $V(\theta)$ for this vector field on the circle.

So, again, I solved the differential equation $-\frac{dV}{d\theta} = 1$ as per the definition of a potential, and got the solution $V(\theta) = -\theta + C$.

In a solution I looked up, it said that there is no single-valued potential $V(\theta)$ for the vector field on the circle because $V(\theta)$ is not $2 \pi$-periodic - i.e., $V(\theta + 2 \pi k) = -(\theta + 2 \pi k) + C = - \theta - 2 \pi k + C \neq - \theta + C = V(\theta)$.

However, and this is where the statement "As usual, $\theta$ and $\theta + 2 \pi k$ are to be regarded as the same point on the circle, for each integer $k$" confuses me: **I mean, if we're assuming that $\theta$ and $\theta+2 \pi k$ are the same point on the circle - i.e., that $\theta = \theta + 2 \pi k$, for all intents and purposes - and $V(\theta) = -\theta + C$ and $V(\theta + 2 \pi k) = -(\theta + 2\pi k)+C$, how does it make any sense that $V(\theta) \neq V(\theta + 2 \pi k)$?**

- Part (c):

> What's the general rule? When does $\dot{\theta} = f(\theta)$ have a single-valued potential?

Again, a solution I read says that in order for $\dot{\theta} = f(\theta)$ to have a single-valued potential, $V(\theta)$ must be $2\pi$-periodic.

So, I'm trying to show that this is true: Solving the equation $\dot{\theta} = -\frac{dV}{d\theta}$, I obtain $V(\theta) = -\int f(\theta)d\theta$.

So, let's choose a constant $C$ such that $V(\theta) = -\int_{0}^{\theta}f(\theta) d\theta$. Then, it seems to me that $2\pi$-periodicity would imply that $V(\theta) = V(\theta + 2\pi k)$ (**which, to me, seems like the exact opposite of single-valued. If someone could explain to me why it's not, it would be extremely helpful!**).

So, **I'd need $- \int_{0}^{\theta}f(\theta) d\theta = -\int_{0}^{\theta + 2 \pi k}f(\theta+2\pi k) d(\theta +2\pi k)$, or $- \int_{0}^{\theta}f(\theta) d\theta + \int_{0}^{\theta + 2 \pi k}f(\theta+2\pi k) d(\theta +2\pi k) = 0$.** Now, I understand that there are a lot of questions asked an answered on here about how to show this when $f$ itself is periodic, but we're not necessarily told that here - we only know about $V$, not $f$. So, **how do I go about showing this?**

I realize I'm asking a lot here, and I'm probably overthinking a great deal of it, but I really want to understand potentials! Thank you for your time and patience!

Comment: A hint:  Notice that $dV/d\theta = - f(\theta)$, that is, $V$ is an antiderivative of $f$ (multiplied by $-1$).  $f$ is $2 \pi$-periodic.  When is an antiderivative of a periodic function itself periodic?

Comment: @user539887 not sure. But, we're given that $V$ is periodic, not $f$.

Comment: As $f$ gives a vector field **on the circle** it must be $2 \pi$-periodic.

Comment: @user539887 thanks! In that case though I still don't know what the conditions have to be in order for the anti derivative of a $2\pi$ periodic function to be itself periodic. Could you please enlighten me?

Comment: I don't understand the setup here. You write $\dot\theta = d\theta/dt$ in the beginning but then you never make any reference to $t$. Shouldn't you be integrating with respect to $t$? How is $\theta$ a function of $t$? How does this give a vector field?

Comment: @ALannister For $V$ to be a $2 \pi$-periodic function it is necessary and sufficient to have $V(0) = V(2 \pi)$.  As any two antiderivatives differ by a constant, assume for definiteness $V(0) = 0$.  Then a necessary and sufficient condition for an antiderivative of a (continuous) $2 \pi$-periodic function $f$ to be $2 \pi$-periodic is $$ \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} f(\theta) \, d\theta = 0.$$

Comment: @ALannister  When the above condition is satisfied, everything is O.K.: there is a single valued potential, unique up to additive constant.  But if not, then we can speak of a countably-valued potential (for its graph you can see [How can I mark the preimage of covering map (spiral on circle)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149693/how-can-i-mark-the-preimage-of-covering-map-spiral-on-circle); $V$ is then a potential, because the vector field $f$ equals the negative of the derivative $dV/d\theta$, no matter which "branch" of $V$ you take.

Comment: @AlexProvost $\theta$ is not a function of $t$, it is a generic point in the **phase space** (that is, the circle, identified with $\mathbb{R}/ 2 \pi \mathbb{Z}$, the real numbers modulo $2 \pi$).  A vector field on the circle is given by a $2\pi$-periodic function.

Comment: @user539887 That was also my original understanding of the question, i.e., the vector field should be given as $f(\theta) = \cos(\theta)$, and not $\dot\theta = \cos(\theta)$. (I can't make sense of the latter.)

Comment: @AlexProvost I'm accustomed to the ODEs jargon, where an autonomous differential equation is identified with a vector field.